# Google Analytics: Can I track conversion rates from specific sources?

Tags: google-analytics

I'm looking around GA to see if I can find a way to track from specific websites and their progress on our website. I need to know the amount of people finding our marketing material on website A, then out of them showing me how many of the website A traffic has then signed up. Is this possible?

I've looked into using PadiTrack but if I wanted to know the results from a specific website, I would have to create a landing page for each website where I post marketing material (I think).

Are there any other ways to track conversion rates like this for specific traffic sources?

Answer (score 1):

You could create an event or destination goal for your signup form, then create an advanced segment that only looks at referral traffic from a specific website. This would give you goal conversion rates from specific traffic sources.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can track conversion from specific sources, here is an example. Click Traffic Source - Sources - All Sources in Google Analytics. Now in the top left area of your report window you'll see Site Usage, Goal Set 1. If you have Goals setup and or named this might be different. Click on the Goals and in the table below you will see each traffic source with the conversion rate it's generated. You can do this from within the Search, Referral and other traffic source areas for more details of which site and or link is generating conversions

[image]