# How do I see the websites that users are coming from?

Tags: google-analytics

I'm certain that at one point I was able to look at a breakdown of inbound URLs.

Now I can't find it anywhere!

It seems like this would be a common use of GA, but I couldn't find instructions for this either on this SE or elsewhere on the Internet.

The closest I found was this question: [“Can I track conversion rates from specific sources?”](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/53109/google-analytics-can-i-track-conversion-rates-from-specific-sources) but one answer there only gets down to the level of seeing all direct traffic (I want names of sites) and the other answer recommends setting up custom goals, which I know I didn't do in the past.

Can anyone point me in the right direction to see traffic by source website again?

Answer (score 2):

You will need to login to GA and then go to the website that you need to look up the data for and then on the left hand side menu there is something called Acquisition from the click on All Referrals. That will show you were the traffic came from.